# Prove these two integrals are equal.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Prove that:
$$\forall n,m \in \Bbb N:\int_0^1 x^m(1-x)^n \,dx=\int_0^1(1-x)^mx^n \,dx$$

I really have no idea.

Comment: Slow day on the hot questions.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting $t=1-x\iff x=1-t$, we have $\mathrm d\mkern1mu x=-\mathrm d\mkern1mu t$,  hence the change of variable formula yields:
$$\int_0^1 x^m(1-x)^n \,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x=\int_1^0(1-t)^m t^n (-\mathrm d\mkern1mu t)=\int_0^1t^n(1-t)^m \,\mathrm d\mkern1mu t=\int_0^1 x^n(1-x)^m \,\mathrm d\mkern1mu x. $$

Comment: I don't see your last step. Why $\int_0^1 t^n(1-t)^m dt=\int_0^1 x^n(1-x)^m dx$ ?

Comment: Because $t$ and $x$ are dummy variables. It is the same with `\sum_{i=1}^5 (2i-1)=\sum_{k=1}^5 (2k-1)`: they're both equal to `25`. In other words: theyre just place-holders.

Comment: Is "dummy variable" the official name of it?

Comment: One also says *bound variable*.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** with $u = 1-x{{{{{}}}}}$.

Comment: Can you tell me more? I tried to use $u=1-x,$ but I was failed.